# Locally smallness of functor categories

Tags: category-theory

How can we show that if $C$ is a small category and $D$ is a locally small category, then $D^C$ is also locally small? And what is a counterexample to show that if $C$ is not small, then $D^C$ is not necessary locally small?

Comment: You need the fact that the product of a small set of small sets is a small set, whereas the product of a large set of small sets may not be a small set.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why we need this? How can I use this?

Comment: Write out the definition of locally small category. Write down the definition of natural transformation. Write out the definition of functor category. If you don't see where to use the fact I mentioned then I'm afraid I can't help you...

Comment: @ZhenLin thank you for your comment. I understood how I can prove that if C be small then D^C is locally small. I am not agree with your argument for the counterexample.

Comment: For a counterexample, see [this paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/1-09abs.html) : any large $C$ will be a counterexample for $D=\mathbf{Set}$.